# Check if values exist in two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

Here is the table number (1)

```
ID    NAME   
1     Adam   
2     Max   
3     Alex
```

and here is the table number (2)

```
ID    USER_ID  AGE 
1       1   
2       2      21
3       3      23
```

i want to check the age of all users from table number (2) , also if the filed empty will echo empty
using php ... i've tried foreach loop and it didn't worked so help me please and sorry for my bad english

best regards .

Comment: simply what i meant select the user id number 1 from the table number 2 where the user_id is 1 witch is will be adam and check if the user put his age if not then echo empty. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have your age column as varchar then use this to check between empty strings or null

```
  SELECT name, if(age =''  or age is null, 'empty',age) age
  FROM   table1
  JOIN   table2 
  ON table1.id = table2.user_id
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a5c5d/3)

Answer (score 0):

You could join the tables and use the `coalesce` function to replace `null` with your custom string (`empty`):

```
SELECT username, COALESCE(age, 'empty')
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON table1.id = table2.user_id
```